# Android Animation not moving text view

Tags: android

I am following a tutorial for animating a text view. While debugging I see that my button press is recognized and my animation start listener is triggered. However I do not see an animation.

blink.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

button and textview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Slide Down"
            android:id="@+id/btnSlideDown"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/slideDownText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is my content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

button and animation

```
slideText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slideDownText);
        slideButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSlideDown);
        slideButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_down);
                animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        System.out.println("start");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        System.out.println("end");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        System.out.println("repeat");
                    }
                });
                slideText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                slideText.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });
```

Any ideas as to why I do not see my text value blinking?

Comment: is it the `R.anim.slide_down` should actually be `R.anim.blink`? Could also be that blink.xml is not in `res/anim` folder.

Comment: I was initially trying slide down, then rotate, then blink. I never renamed the anim file but changed the contents. Sorry for the confusion.